# Payum - PaymentDetails object in done action where is

Tags: php, symfony, payum

im on done aciton and dont know how to get paymentDetails object...

here is manual : 
http://payum.forma-dev.com/documentation/0.8/PayumBundle/purchase_done_action

i try get object PaymentDetails from step before 
http://payum.forma-dev.com/documentation/0.8/PayumBundle/simple_purchase_examples/paypal_express_checkout

UPDATE1

```
public function doneAction(){

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    /**
     * @var $token PayumSecurityToken
     */
    $token = $this->get('payum.security.http_request_verifier')->verify($request);

    /**
     * @var $details PaymentDetails
     */
    $details = $token->getDetails();


    var_dump($details);
```

give

```
object(Payum\Core\Model\Identificator)[345]
  protected 'class' => string 'ed\partnerBundle\Entity\PaymentDetails' (length=38)
  protected 'id' => int 1
```

UPDATE2

```
 $details = unserialize($token->getDetails());

ContextErrorException: Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 40 bytes in /home/grek/public_html/edpartner/src/ed/partnerBundle/Controller/PaymentController.php line 110
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Payum\Core\Model\Identificator` is expected result. There two ways to get details:

1. Using storage:

   ```
   <?php
   $registry = $this->get('payum');
   $storage = $registry->getStorageForClass(
       $token->getDetails()->getClass(), 
       $token->getPaymentName()
   );

   $details = $storage->findModelByIdentificator($token->getDetails());
   ```
2. Executing a request. Here `StorageExtension` will set it to the request.

   ```
   <?php
   $status = new BinaryMaskStatusRequest($token);

   $this->get('payum')->getPayment($token->getPaymentName())->execute($status);

   $details = $status->getModel();
   ```

Comment: I have used the second approach and I can confirm it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$registry = $this->get('payum');
$storage = $registry->getStorage(
    $token->getDetails()->getClass(), 
    $token->getPaymentName()
);
```

if you are using 0.13 then make sure to include the use Payum\Core\Request\GetHumanStatus; in order to get the human readable status. To do it in 0.13 use the code provided in the documentation

here is a code example

```
$token = $this->get('payum.security.http_request_verifier')->verify($request);
$payment = $this->get('payum')->getPayment($token->getPaymentName());
$status->getValue();
```